# Is it possible to add two buttons to an infowindow on Android, each with its own click listener?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, infowindow

i have use a google map. i have added a marker with info windows. if add add two button in the infowindows it is not possible to add clicklistener per buttons. i know that "The info window that is drawn is not a live view." but i am searching for a solution

i have add two buttons with event cliklistener but it dosent work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Info windows in Google Maps are not live views, which means they are rendered as images, not placed in the view hierarchy. Because of this, you cannot directly set an OnClickListener for the buttons inside an info window.

Comment: yes, i know , but i am searching for a alternative solutions

Comment: could you help me over here ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786965/facing-issue-while-validating-amongst-the-edittexts-in-recyclerview